# Change default html template in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to change my default HTML template for new component in Angular 6.
I created the app using angular-cli

```
ng new projectname --routing
```

and created a new component using

```
ng g c component
```

but every time it generated a default HTML template

```
<p>
  It works
</p>
```

I want to change this template with a custom template so that every time when a new component is created, it follows my custom template, not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's currently possible. The file responsible for creating the templates seems to be [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts), and there's no option for a custom template in the [responsible function](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts#L129).

The file that get's created by `ng new component` is [this html file](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/files/__name%40dasherize%40if-flat__/__name%40dasherize__.component.html) - so what you could do is to fork angular-cli, edit this to whatever default template you want and you'll have your own for every component creation.

It's on you to decide if it's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is now possible through Angular Schematics discussed here in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#schematic it seems to provide a means to customize the angular add/generate commands.

There's also a pretty good write up on the new feature here: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4